# Validate a UL with angular?

Tags: angularjs

Im using angular and chosen.js.

What chosen does is add a UL to my form, with all of my (now hidden) drop down elements in it.

I was just wondering, is there a way to validate this UL with angular?

Comment: use plugin callbacks to update model, no such thing as validating a `UL`

Comment: If you can show an example plunker, we could perhaps help.  You can always set form validation state directly in your controller.